# PHPMailer no longer working on GoDaddy

Tags: phpmailer

We have set up PHPMailer on our GoDaddy hosted website. We are aware of the particular settings GoDaddy requires in order for the plugin to work so we used those.

```
$m = new PHPMailer;

$m->isSMTP();

$m->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
//$m->SMTPDebug  = 2;

$m->Port = 25;
$m->SMTPAuth = false;
$m->SMTPSecure = false;

$m->CharSet  = "UTF-8";

$m->From = 'ouremail@godaddydomain.fm';
$m->FromName = 'OUR COMPANY';
$m->AddAddress($userEmail);
```

This worked perfectly for months, but about a week ago we started getting: 
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

We haven't touched the code for months so it's not something we changed.

Has anyone run into this issue in the last couple weeks? Any ideas on how to solve it? I've been on customer support with GoDaddy for 45 minutes and that did not help at all.

Thanks

Comment: Does GoDaddy have forums?  Did you ask there?  This sounds like it's GoDaddy not phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 3 hours! in chat with customer service, the only thing that helped was them sending me a sample form that used PHPMailer to send an email. After reading the code I realized that they are using an old version of PHPMailer. If you use the latest version it just doesn't work.

The version that works is 5.1. Host needs to be set to 'localhost'.